# toggle class cookie remember state

Tags: jquery, cookies, toggleclass, remember-me

I'm horribly new to JQuery, Javascript & otherwise, so sorry if this is super simple!

The issue is that i have a link which adds a class to a different div when clicked. click again and it removes the class via toggleClass.

I've managed to simplify the code down to something less stressful, but i can't seem to 1) attach a cookie ( or maybe i am and am just failing to see it ) & 2) attach the cookie to a bit of script that would recall the state of the div class automatically.

I've poked around for a while, but found the common denominator is mostly just me as far as failing to get the code to work. how would you personally tackle this issue?

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('[data-toggle="offcanvas"]').click(function () {
            $('#wrap2').toggleClass('toggled');
            $.cookie('sidebar-pref', 'use-sidebar', { expires: 30 });
        });  
    });
```

the coding that toggles it on & off which i've had no issues with--

```
<button type="button" class="hamburger is-closed animated fadeInLeft" data-toggle="offcanvas">
    <span class='awesome'></span>menu
</button>
</a>
</button>

<div id='wrap2'>
<div id="page-content-wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    Main content goes here  
  </div>
</div>
    </div>
```

and the relevant wrapper code

to clarify-- click *menu link* and have `.toggled` added to `#wrap2`, click again and have `.toggled` removed from `#wrap2`. i'm okay with code rewrites if necessary.

thank you!

Comment: Your HTML seems incomplete, can you add more? your code is almost working but for some minor tweaks (need the rest of the HTML to be certain)

Comment: ahaha may have been more tired than i thought when i asked this question. for the sidebar itself, here is the relevant code `<div id='wrap2'>
<div id="page-content-wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    Main content goes here  
  </div>
</div>` there is an extra closing tag for the button that was just an accident as well. edited into op